# The theorem of determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

How do I prove the backwards theorem of the theorem below:
The matrix A is invertible if and only if det(A)!=0.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you defining the determinant? Can you use the characterization that it is the product of the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use that

$$A\cdot \tilde{A}=\det{A}\cdot I_n$$

where $\tilde{A}$ is the comatrice of $A$. The term $\tilde{a}_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}A_{ji }$ where $A_{ij}$ is the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ determinant obtained from $A$ by crossing the $i^{th}$  and the $j^{th}$ column.

The identity can be proved by straightforward computation of the general term of the product and the development of a determinant along a line or a column. All the non diagonal terms are $0$ because they correspond to a determinant where a column is repeated (convince yourself of that) and the diagonal terms are equal to $\det{A}$.

With this identity in hand if $\det{A}$ is invertible we have $A^{-1}=(\det{A})^{-1}\cdot \tilde{A}$

Answer (score 0):

If $\det(A) \neq 0$ then $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}adj(A)$ where $adj(A)$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix of $A$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is invertible, it is a product of elementary matrices and each of these matrices have non-zero determinant, hence $\det(A) \neq 0$.